# Function not returning Max value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have written below function to return max date

```
Alter function MAXdate(@DATE1 date,@DATE2 date,@DATE3 date)
returns date
as
begin
       declare @max as date
       set @max = ''

       if(@DATE1> @DATE2)
       set @max = @DATE1
       else
       set @max = @DATE2

       if(@max >@DATE3)
       set @max= @DATE3

   return @max   
end
```

But when i execute the function, I am not getting max value

```
select dbo.MAXdate('9/8/2008','12/1/2008','3/3/2008')
```

Can any one please help me analyse , why i am not getting max value?

Comment: are the dates Day/Month/Year or Month/Day/Year?

Comment: You could also; `return (select max(d) from (select @DATE1 as d union select @DATE2 union select @DATE3) T)`

Answer (score 7):

Your last test condition should be

```
if(@DATE3 > @max )
   set @max= @DATE3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(@max >@DATE3)
   set @max= @DATE3
```

should be

```
if(@DATE3>@max)
   set @max= @DATE3
```